# How can I use openstreet map to order waypoints?

Tags: ruby, openstreetmap

I saw in articles that OpenStreet map provides an API that, given a route with an origin and destination and multiple (unlimited?) waypoints it sorts the waypoints according to the best route.
I couldn't tell which endpoint it was. Could someone point me to the part of the documentation that explains how to achieve this? Is there a ruby gem that wraps up this endpoint request?

Thank you very much

Comment: Are you looking for this? https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing

Comment: Yes, thank you, I had seen that but I can't find the doc on how to accomplish what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the traveling salesman problem. There is more than one OSM-based router for solving this problem. According to a [similar question at help.openstreetmap.org](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/55994/traveling-salesman-routing):

> All major OSM routing engines support this:
>
> - Mapzen's [Valhalla](https://github.com/valhalla/valhalla)
>     ("Valhalla also includes tools like time+distance matrix computation,
>     isochrones, elevation sampling, map matching and tour optimization
>     (Travelling Salesman)."),
> - Mapbox's
>     [OSRM](http://project-osrm.org/docs/v5.5.1/api/#trip-service) ("The
>     trip plugin solves the Traveling Salesman Problem using a greedy
>     heuristic...")
> - Graphhopper uses the [JSPrit
>     library](https://github.com/graphhopper/jsprit/blob/master/docs/Traveling%20salesman%20problem.md)
>     for route optimization ("TSP problem can be modelled by defining a
>     vehicle routing problem...")
>
> None of these services have a free and unlimited online offering (it
>   would quickly be abused by people trying to save on their own AWS
>   cost). Mapzen has an offer where you register a free API key and use
>   that. OSRM doesn't need an API key, you can just use it. Graphhopper
>   requires registration and while they have a free trial, I don't think
>   they have a free tier.
>
> All three are Open Source and you can install and use them without
>   limits locally.

For [GraphHopper](https://graphhopper.com/api/1/docs/route-optimization/) take a look at the [Route Optimization API](https://graphhopper.com/api/1/docs/route-optimization/). For OSRM see the [trip plugin](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/blob/master/docs/http.md#trip-service).

Comment: Very useful answer. So what you are saying is that I may not accomplish what I want through and API but installing the software on my own system right? I don't really care about the service being free, I just want to resolve the issue of sorting around 100 waypoints. I thought OpenStreetMap did this.

Comment: This is a rather heavy task usually not required by ordinary people except for business cases (e.g. mail services). I guess this is the reason why most services don't offer this feature via a free API. So yes, It looks like you have to install one of these softwares yourself.

Also note that OSM is just a database. There is no "OSM API" available except for the editing API. Most OSM-based APIs are provided by third-parties.

Answer (score 0):

Set up your own OpenStreetMap server - this way you won't be incurring data access fees every time your app needs to run maps queries. 
Specifically, install the **Valhalla** maps server. It's a free application. Best to install it on a Linux box:

https://github.com/valhalla/valhalla

Or download and run the docker image in Docker instead:

https://hub.docker.com/r/abihf/valhalla/

https://github.com/interline-io/valhalla-docker

The server provides an API specifically for ordering waypoints:
https://valhalla.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/optimized/api-reference/